# dropdownlist not passing selected values in form via POST

Tags: php, arrays, html

I have a registration form which includes 2 dropdown lists, one of which changes depending on which option in the first dropdown list is selected.Upon clicking the button submit, all the values in the form are passed successfully, EXCEPT for the values in the dropdown list.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sign Up</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) {
    var retail = new Array('Books','Computer Accessories','Electronics', 'Fashion','Others');
    var dining = new Array('Asian','Chinese','French','Italian','Japanese','Korean','Western','Others');

    switch (ddl1.value) {
        case 'Retail':
            document.getElementById(ddl2).options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < retail.length; i++) {
                createOption(document.getElementById(ddl2), retail[i], retail[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'Dining':
            document.getElementById(ddl2).options.length = 0; 
        for (i = 0; i < dining.length; i++) {
            createOption(document.getElementById(ddl2), dining[i], dining[i]);
            }
            break;

            default:
                document.getElementById(ddl2).options.length = 0;
            break;
    }

}

function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = value;
    opt.text = text;
    ddl.options.add(opt);
}
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#FFF">
<div id="container_register">
<div id="header_register"></div>
<div id="welcome_register">Register</div>
<div id="box_register">     
  <form id="RegForm" name="RegForm" method="POST" action="Register.php">
    <table width="460" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Username*</td><td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" size="30" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email*</td><td><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" size="30" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Verify Email*</td><td><input type="text" name="vemail" maxlength="50" size="30" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password*</td><td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50" size="30" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Verify Password*</td><td><input type="password" name="vpassword" maxlength="50" size="30" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Business Name*</td><td><input type="text" name="bizname" maxlength="30" size="30" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Verify Business Name*</td><td><input type="text" name="vbizname" maxlength="30" size="30" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Business Type*</td>
            <td>:
            <select name="type" id="ddl" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,'ddl2')">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
            <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
            </select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Business SubType*</td>
            <td>:
            <select id="ddl2" name="subtype">
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Info</td><td><textarea name="info" rows="5" cols="24" maxlength="300"></textarea>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="SUBMIT" name="Button" value="Register"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><?PHP if(isset($errormsg)){echo"$errormsg";}?></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><font color="#FF0000"></font></td>              
        </tr>             
    </table>
  </form>      
</div> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon submitting the form, i am directed to the processing page where i echo print_r($POST), and i get

```
Array ( [username] => uname [email] => email [vemail] => vemail [password] => pw [vpassword] => vpw [bizname] => name [vbizname] => vname [Button] => Register )
```

***Question:***
How do i pass the values of the selected values in the dropdown list AND the textarea?

Comment: after copy/pasting your code into jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/wXmVP/) and examining the posted header, i can just say: your html/javascript works completely fine, you have a problem in php!

Comment: Your provided code works perfectly fine in php as well.